# Is there a way to link JAX-RS resource to another resource like in Spring HATEOAS?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard, hateoas, spring-hateoas

In Spring we've got `@ExposesResourceFor` annotation which can link our resource with other resources. Thanks to this our Value objects (representations) can know nothing of the actual resources.

**Is there a way to do it in JAX-RS? I'm using Dropwizard with Jersey and Jackson and all I see is `@InjectLinks` annotation which I can use in a value object like this:**

```
public class UserGroup {
    @JsonProperty
    public String name;

    @InjectLinks(GroupsResource.class)
    public URI myResource;

    public UserGroup(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**But unfortunatelly my Value Objects should know nothing about Resources, so I'm asking can I do such linking on the level of resources - link in spring-hateoas in controllers, as mentioned above.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `@InjectLinks`, you don't *have* to declare the links in your model class. You can create a *"wrapper"* representation class, as shown in [declarative-linking](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/declarative-linking) from the [Jersey examples](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/) (though this solution is not really on the resource class level as you wish).

Another possible solution (rather than declarative linking) is to use the JAX-RS 2.0 [`Link`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Link.html) class, and do the linking *programmatically* (with no ties to the Jersey implementation/annotations). You can either add the links to your response headers, as see [**here**](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/uris-and-links.html#d0e9335), or add `Link`s to you model classes, as seen [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26084130/2587435) (or use the wrapper class for this also, so as to not to invade your model classes)

**Some Resources**

- [Declarative Hyperlinking](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/declarative-linking.html#d0e9538)
- [Using Link for headers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/uris-and-links.html#d0e9335)

Comment: I've decided to go with the header approach. Thanks!